# Matplotlib weird x labels on plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, analysis

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.plot(time_stamps,b,"b.--",label="Status")
ax1.plot(time_stamps,d,"y.--",label="Process")
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax1.set_xlim(ax2.get_xlim())

mymajorformat = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
myminorFormat = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')



ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator
(MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,5)))


ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator
(MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,60)))

ax2.tick_params(axis='x',which="minor",length=10, 
rotation=30,labelsize=12)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which="major",length=10, 
rotation=90,labelsize=11)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mymajorformat)
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(myminorFormat)

ax2.set_xticks(ax1.get_xlim())
```

I am not allowed to include images. As you can see i have a weird x description (red box) on beginning and end of plot also on bottom x axis at the end. How to hide this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLx9y.png)

Answer (score 0):

this is working

ax2.set_xticks([])